# How to find the first ancestor node from two leaf nodes in the same level in a binary tree

Tags: c++, algorithm

[image]

The above shows a 3(2?) level binary tree. My question is how to find the ancestor node from two leaf nodes in the same level in a binary tree? For example, the ancestor node of (3, 4) is 1. The ancestor node of (3, 5) is 0. The root node of (5, 6)is 2. If given two leaf nodes, how to find their first common ancestor node? I am using C++. My approach and pseucode is like

```
int mother{} \\ an algorithm to find mother node
int n1(7), n2(11); \\two integer leaf nodes.
int a1(-1), a2(-2);
while(a1 != a2)
{ 
 a1=mother(n1);
 a2=mother(n2);
 n1=a1;
 n2=a2;
}
```

I thought this is too complicated. I am wondering any simpler algorithm exist?

Comment: It's trivial to save a binary tree to an array. Look up on how to store binary tree in array. Then print that array. You will instantly come up with a solution

Comment: Are you given just the children node? Or do you have access to the root node?

Comment: I think your solution might be the simplest but I don't know of any others. In other words you want the root of the smallest subtree that contains a and b. There might be an algorithm for that.

Comment: I think you are looking for the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_ancestor

Comment: @Moop I was given everything. I just need to figure out a simple algorithm to find out the first common ancestor of two leaf nodes.

Comment: You usually don't have direct access to the parent node of each node in a tree, so you can't just get `parent(node)`. You'll have to start at the root and locate both nodes, then compare the path you took somehow.

Comment: As "mother" is a sacred word in most cultures, the current preferred nomenclature for nodes is root, parent, child, children, sibling rather than mother, father, son, and daughter, etc.

Comment: @JohnMurray That's funny. LoL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algorithm to find the first common ancestor (FCA) of two leaf nodes (LFs)

1. Create a function that will return a vector containing the sequential list of nodes needed to reach a given leaf node with root being the first node in the list

   `vector<Node> GetPathToNode(Node root, Node leafNode);`

   If the binary tree is organized properly, then this should be able to traverse the quickest path to the leaf node directly.  If the tree is not organized properly, then this would require a complete tree traversal algorithm to find the node and to then to determine the shortest path to the node.
2. Call GetPathToNode(root, leafNodeA); which returns vector pathA
3. Call GetPathToNode(root, leafNodeB); which returns vector pathB
4. Create a function that will compare the two paths and find the first element that is different in the two vectors.  Then, return the element just before the first different element.

   `Node GetLastEquivalentNode(vector<Node> pathA, vector<Node> pathB);`

Of course, this could be further optimized by replacing step three with a call to a third function which mirrors GetPathToNode(), but which takes an additional parameter:  vector pathA.  This third function would exit once it had reached the first non-common ancestor and return the node just above that.

In reality, the first common ancestor takes a node centric view (looking bottom up).  However, the algorithm has to start from the root and move down to find the last common ancestor.